# How to get text from slide in swiper slider

Tags: javascript, text, selector, swiper.js

I need get text from slide. My team use `swiper` slider.  I read document for this slider, try to get text like this:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper){
      var index = swiper.actionIndex;
      var selector = 'div[swiper-slide-index="'+index+'"]';
      var value = $(this).find(selector).text();
      console.log(value);
  }
})
```

but I don't get text.
Also I have used:

```
var value = $(.swiper-slide-active).text();
console.log(value);
```

But I get nothing.

Comment: Are you getting the object right? try with .html()

Comment: Swiper slider has little to do with getting text from a DOM element.

Comment: @SlavnJudin i edited your tags to include swiper. if you click on swiper other questions related to swiper js will come up. Maybe have a browse through them; it might assist you

Answer (score 0):

```
var priceSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
 onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper){
  var value = $('#price .swiper-slide-active').text();
 console.log(value);
 }                                          
})
```

Its how I get text;